# How do you maintain continous client / server communication?

Tags: python

I am trying to have a client connect to my server, and have a stream of communication between them. The only reason the connection should break is due to network errors, or unless the client wants to stop talking.

The issue I am running into is keeping the handler in a tight loop, and parsing the JSON.

My server code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SocketServer
import socket
import json
import time

class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):

        while 1:
            try:
                networkData = (self.request.recv(1024).strip())

                try:
                    jsonInputData = json.loads(networkData)
                    print jsonInputData

                    try: 
                        if jsonInputData['type'] == 'SAY_HI':
                            print "HI"
                    except Exception, e:
                        print "no hi"
                        pass

                    try: 
                        if jsonInputData['type'] == 'GO_AWAY':
                            print "Going away!"
                    except Exception, e:
                        print "no go away"
                        pass

                except Exception, e:
                    pass
                    #time.sleep(0.001)
                    #print "JSON Error", e

            except Exception, e:
                #time.sleep(0.001)
                pass
                #print "No message", e

server = MyTCPServer(('192.168.1.115', 13373), MyTCPServerHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

My client code is simple :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import json
import time
import sys

hostname = '192.168.1.103'
port = 13373

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((hostname,port))

except Exception, e:
    print "Error, could not open socket: ", e

data  = {'type':'SAY_HI'}

sock.send(json.dumps(data))

data  = {'type':'SAY_BYE'}

sock.send(json.dumps(data))
```

Sometimes I'll see the messages being sent, "SAY_HI" and "SAY_BYE", but most of the times, no data is being displayed on the server side.

Comment: does it work if you use `sock.sendall(json.dumps(data))` in your client instead of just `sock.send(...` ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is *really* not clear, but calling `self.request.recv(1024)` is very likely not what you want to do.  You're eliminating all of the nice application-level handling that TCP will happily do for you.  If you change that to `self.request.recv(8)` or a similarly very small number (such that `recv()` returns whenever it receives data, and doesn't try to fill your buffer), you may get better results.

Ultimately this is super-simplistic change, even if it works, that will not work in a larger context.  You will need to be handling exceptions from your json parser on the server side and waiting for more data until an entire well-formed message is received.

This is a hopelessly more complex subject than will be handled generally in any SO answer.  If you're going to be doing any amount of raw sockets programming, you absolutely *must* own a copy of [Unix Network Programming, Volume 1](http://amzn.com/0131411551).

Comment: Interesting, that might be the issue where the message does not come in one packet. I don't see a reason why it wouldn't come in one packet, since the messages are not big.

Comment: @user791953: `recv()` *does not return* when a packet is received.  It returns when it fills the buffer or when the connection is closed.  As your connection is never closed, it doesn't return until it fills the buffer, and thus your buffer is going to contain a lot more than one packet's worth of data and `json.loads()` is often not going to be able to do anything useful with it.  Normally in a situation like this there would be some kind of marker to indicate the end of a message (like a header that indicates message length), that allows a server-side parser to deal with this kind of data.

Comment: You can much better see what is going on by not ignoring your exception handlers - you should print the tracebacks in each exception handler (particularly the inner one, which I suspect is happening frequently with a json parse error).

Comment: Gotcha, I followed the example given on http://thomasfischer.biz/python-simple-json-tcp-server-and-client/ and figured that it would work the same way, except leaving the socket open. How come using recv() in that case works fine? And yes, it's mostly JSON parsing errors, which you are correct about.

Comment: @user791953: In that example the client closes the connection every time it sends a message, which means that your `recv()` call will return regardless of whether the buffer is full.  Since you're leaving the connection open, you need to have some other mechanism for indicating the boundary between application messages.  (In fact in that example the buffer size probably ought to be a lot larger - if you send it a json message over 1024 bytes it'll raise an exception and not parse your message).

Comment: Hmm, would it then be easier to not leave the connection open and handle with the messages separately? As you mentioned before, I would have to pass the server some length so it knows when to stop reading.

Comment: @user791953: Easier, yes, for sure (just make sure you make the buffer bigger than any application message you're going to receive, or better, write a buffered message handler).  However, it might still be suboptimal as far as how many connections your client creates, etc. (as creating connections is more computationally expensive than sending data on existing ones).  But yes, if you don't close the connection you need to enclose your json message in another protocol that describes the number of bytes in the app message so the server can parse (or not) when the buffer is full.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user791953: added a link to a book that is the absolute bible on sockets programming, which you will likely find very useful if you are doing raw sockets programming regularly.